# Logarithmic complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

It's diffcult for me to understand logarithmic complexity of algorithm.

For example

```
for(int j=1; j<=n; j*=2){
    ...
}
```

Its complexity is O(log<sub>2</sub>N)

So what if it is `j*=3`? The complexity will then be O(log<sub>3</sub>N)?

Comment: The last slide of [this document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) explains the general case of logarithmic loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could say yes as long as the loop body is O(1).

However, note that log<sub>3</sub>N = log<sub>2</sub>N / log<sub>2</sub>3, so it is also O(log<sub>2</sub>N), since the constant factor does not matter.

Also note it is apparent from this argument, for any fixed constant `k`, O(log<sub>k</sub>N) is also O(log<sub>2</sub>N), since you could substitute `3` with `k`.

Comment: That is why logarithmic complexity is usually stated as just "log N" without specifying the base.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Mmm, I always thought of plain `log` as log base 2, but your way of looking at that make sense too.

Comment: In Big O notation what matters is not Log2 or Log3, what matters is how does the algorithm complexity grow with respect to the input size.  Constant time, Log, Linear and Exp are the common ones.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, yes.
Let's assume that your for loop looks like this:

```
for (int j = 1; j < n; j *= a) {...}
```

where `a` is some const.
If the `for` loop executes k times, then in the last iteration, j will be equal to a<sup>k</sup>. And since N = O(j) and j = O(a<sup>k</sup>), N = O(a<sup>k</sup>). It follows that k = O(log<sub>a</sub>N). Once again, `for` loop executes k times, so time complexity of this algorithm is O(k) = O(log<sub>a</sub>N).